# How do I format my SQL in my XML file such that C# doesn't think the query is part of the XML?

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I have several queries stored in an XML File.  The entry giving me issues is:

```
<Xiphos>
        SELECT 
      'AccountGrants', 
          cast (STUFF (SUBSTRING(b.PiiData,0,PATINDEX ('%</AccountNumber>%',b.PiiData ) ),1,24,'') as char(40) ) as Gen2accountNumber  
      ,[GrantTypeId] as GrantType-- constant always 1
      ,[GrantAmount]  as GrantedAmount
      ,[UsedAmount]
      ,[AwardedDate]
      ,[ExpirationDate]
      FROM [Xiphos].[dbo].[AccountGrants]a
      join Xiphos.dbo.Accounts b
      on a.AccountId = b.AccountId
      where b.FinancialInstitutionId =@InstitutionId
      order by Gen2accountNumber,AwardedDate;
</Xiphos>
```

The 3rd line of the query that has "`</AccountNumber>`" in it is causing my project to not compile because it thinks this is a malformed XML statement (or missing the opening AccountNumber).

I can't seem to figure out how to either reformat the query or modify my XML such that this doesn't happen.

The PiiData column causing the problem looks like:

```
<PiiData><AccountNumber>150</AccountNumber>
```

Comment: How did you create that XML file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with the `<` and `>` characters in your query - they are treated as normal XML and you need to escape them - there are a couple of ways to do this.

You can enclose the query in a [`<![CDATA[]]>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section:

```
<Xiphos>
  <![CDATA[
        SELECT 
      'AccountGrants', 
          cast (STUFF (SUBSTRING(b.PiiData,0,PATINDEX ('%</AccountNumber>%',b.PiiData ) ),1,24,'') as char(40) ) as Gen2accountNumber  
      ,[GrantTypeId] as GrantType-- constant always 1
      ,[GrantAmount]  as GrantedAmount
      ,[UsedAmount]
      ,[AwardedDate]
      ,[ExpirationDate]
      FROM [Xiphos].[dbo].[AccountGrants]a
      join Xiphos.dbo.Accounts b
      on a.AccountId = b.AccountId
      where b.FinancialInstitutionId =@InstitutionId
      order by Gen2accountNumber,AwardedDate;
  ]]>
</Xiphos>
```

Alternatively, escape them by using their entity references - `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`.

Answer (score 1):

It is malformed XML. XML has 5 reserved characters that are syntactically significant to the XML parser. These characters *must* be escaped if they are not part of the XML syntax. Here are the 5 reserved characters:

- `<`
  Escape with named entity `&amp;lt;`.
- `>`
  Escape with named entity `&amp;gt;`.
- `&`
  Escape with named entity `&amp;amp;`.
- `"`
  Escape with named entity `&amp;quot;`.
- `'`
  Escape with named entity `&amp;apos;`.

You may escape them with the named entities listed for each character, or you may enclose the data containing the reserved characters in a CDATA section:

```
<element>
  <![CDATA[
    This is character data only
  ]]>
</element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) to escape the `<` and `>` symbols in your query. This will make them be interpreted as literal text instead of part of the XML structure itself.

Use `&lt;` ("less-than") for `<` and `&gt;` ("greater-than") for `>`.

Answer (score 0):

XML CData section?

[Xml Cdata](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above answers used together would do the trick.